# What is the fastest way to read from a small (on the order of 10 elements) vector of class pointers in parallel?

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization

I am looking for the fastest way to have multiple threads reading from the same small vector (one which is not static but will only ever be changed by the main thread and only ever when the child threads are not reading from it) of pointers.

I've tried using a shared `std::vector` of pointers which is somewhat faster than a shared array of pointers but still slower per thread... I thought that the reason for that is the threads reading so close together in memory causing false sharing, but I am unsure. 
    I'm hoping there is either a way around that since the data is read only when the threads are accessing it or there's an entirely different approach that is faster. Below is a minimal example

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>

namespace chrono=std::chrono;

class A {
public:
    A(int n=1) {
        a=n;
    }
    int a;
};

void tfunc();

int nelements=10;
int nthreads=1;

std::vector<A*> elements;
std::atomic<int> complete;
std::atomic<int> remaining;
std::atomic<int> next;
std::atomic<int> tnow;
int tend=1000000;

int main() {
    complete=false;
    remaining=0;
    next=0;
    tnow=0;
    for (int i=0; i < nelements; i++) {
        A* a=new A();
        elements.push_back(a);
    }

    std::thread threads[nthreads];
    for (int i=0; i < nthreads; i++) {
        threads[i]=std::thread(tfunc);
    }
    auto begin=chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    while (tnow < tend) {
        remaining=nthreads;
        next=0;
        tnow += 1;
        while (remaining > 0) {}
        // if {elements} is changed it is changed here
    }
    complete=true;
    for (int i=0; i < nthreads; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
    auto complete=chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto elapsed=chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(complete-begin).count();
    std::cout << std::setw(2) << nthreads << "Time - " << elapsed << std::endl;
}

void tfunc() {
    int sum=0;
    int tpre=0;
    int curr=0;
    while (tnow == 0) {}
    while (!complete) {
        if (tnow-tpre > 0) {
            tpre=tnow;
            while (remaining > 0) {
                curr=next++;
                if (curr > nelements) break;
                for (int i=0; i < nelements; i++) {
                    if (i != curr) {
                        sum += elements[i] -> a;
                    }
                }
                remaining--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which for `nthreads` between 1 and 10 on my system outputs (the times are in microseconds)

```
1  Time - 281548
2  Time - 404926
3  Time - 546826
4  Time - 641898
5  Time - 714259
6  Time - 812776
7  Time - 922391
8  Time - 994909
9  Time - 1147579
10 Time - 1199838
```

I am wondering if there is a faster way to do this or if such a parallel operation will always be slower than serial due to the smallness of the vector.

Comment: Since all threads are reading from the same vector and them perform some trivial operations with the elements of the vector, this program is I/O limited, and will most likely perform worse than the serial version because of cache misses from false sharing.

Comment: There aren't really that many different ways of reading through a vector, that I can think of. Come to think of it, I can only think of one way. And you've got it.

Comment: @HenriMenke That is what I was thinking was causing the per thread slowdown, but I was hoping there would be a way around that - either with a different scheme entirely or some way to change the memory accessing to be more efficient. I wouldn't exactly be surprised if there is not but I thought it worth asking

Comment: The read sharing shouldn't be a problem, but all those accesses to atomic variables might be.

Comment: You can mitigate that to some extend by adhering to the “first touch” principle and pinning threads.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I had not thought of that, I will try an approach without the atomics and see what happens. Thanks

Comment: Another question is how many cores do you have available? If your `(threads > cores)`, then you are also creating a scheduling slowdown.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The system I am testing on has an i7-8750H with 6 cores and 2 threads per core

Comment: I have to agree with @1201ProgramAlarm.  The false sharing is not the main problem but the atomics with their implicit locks.  With a single thread `perf` reports `55,196,511 lock_cycles.cache_lock_duration` but with four threads `749,154,831 lock_cycles.cache_lock_duration` and the total number of cycles skyrockets as well.

Comment: @HenriMenke It looks like I was asking slightly the wrong question, I will redesign with less reliance on the atomic variables. Thanks for the help

Comment: Nit - `auto complete` shadows `std::atomic<int> complete;`

Comment: Testing on my platform (and platforms do vary greatly), atomics are about x40 slower than regular primitives.  So when you need them, they're awesome.  But if you don't need them, they incur a huge performance hit.

Comment: @Eljay After switching to a less atomic dependent scheme I am seeing much faster times, clearly that is an important lesson I had missed about atomics